# Changes to ndb not reflected directly

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

If I do a put or delete on a ndb database, and then directly after a redirect to a "view" page handler that reads the contents of that database, the changes to the database are never reflected unless I reload the view page. I guess ndb works asynchronously.

This is the handler of a post call, for deleting an entry in the database. It works alright but returns "too fast". Can I change it to work synchronously or do I have some other option, like using an on-ready return block?

```
queryApps = MjdocumentApp.query(MjdocumentApp.appleid == appleid)
mjdocumentApp = queryApps.get()
if mjdocumentApp == None:
    return # none existed

mjdocumentApp.key.delete()

self.redirect('/admin_editmjdoc?name=apps')
```

Comment: Check this answer.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17192111/8418

Comment: I don't see how it's related. I need a notification of some kind when delete/put operations are ready.

Comment: It is 100% related. You need to read up on Eventual Consistancy.  There is no notification. If you delete an entity, it is deleted, however you indexes (that your query is based on is not up to date). The only way to check, is to fetch the entity by key. There are also a heap of other questions relating to eventual consistency.

Comment: Ok I will read up on Eventual Consistancy.